# How to identify Digi CM Console Server via command line/SSH?

Tags: networking

Digi CM Console Server is a Secure Access and Management for Servers and Network Devices

https://www.digi.com/products/networking/infrastructure-management/console-servers/digicm#overview

How do we identify their model number or hardware version from CLI/SSH?

Also, how do we get their serial number also from CLI/SSH?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

SNMP is the usual way to do this.

On the Digi console servers, because a lot of the configuration is menu-based, I believe it's a bit more challenging to identify via SSH.  However, the device model and firmware version is displayed when you enter the `configmenu` screen.  See page 13 & 14 of the [Digi CM User Guide](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/pdfs/90000301-88.pdf).